# Ошибка при подключении и компиляции библиотеки dglopengl - "Could not create output file .. dcu"

Tags: delphi, opengl, delphi-7

хотел начать учить opengl для проекта вместе с delphi, подключил библиотеку dglopengl и запустил компиляцию. Работаю, кстати, в Rad Studio. В итоге сообщение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где мне найти такой файл? Или как избавиться от этой проблемы? Компилятор прочитывает все файлы, переносит их в отдельную страницу проекта, но не хочет компилировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас, вероятно, Delphi запущена не из под админа, и у нее нет прав для записи в "Program Files". Перезапустите IDE с правами Администратора, или переустановите в другую папку (которая не будет их требовать).